# Python package raises ModuleNotFoundError on calling an entry-point except if installed in editable mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging

I have a Python package that at first appears to install just fine, but when calling on one of the entry points raises a `ModuleNotFoundException`. The module is otherwise found just fine with both `import package` from the interactive interpreter as well as with `python -m package.etc`. **But** if I try to call on the entry-point directly (flike `python -m package.etc.main`) it will raise an `AttributeError` saying that the module has no attribute `__path__`.

I can see the package if I do `pip list`.

The project is currently set up with the "template" `pyproject.toml` and only `setup.cfg`, but the behaviour is essentially the same (the traceback looks slightly different but the error is the same) when using `setup.py` over `pyproject.toml`, both with `pip` but also if I invoke `setup.py` directly. The structure of the project is:

```
package
├── __init__.py
├── cli
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── entry.py
├── file.py
```

I get the same behaviour if doing this in a virtual environment as when I do it with a userspace (`--user`) install.

Modifying the environment variable `${PYTHONPATH}` fixes the issue, and installing the package in editable mode works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the issue was that I had something like:

```
[options]
packages = find:

[options.packages.find]
include =
  README.md
```

in my `setup.cfg`, and it appears as if the declaration of `include` was exclusive which led to the package not being included in the installation, which still worked when installed in editable mode (presumably because editable mode only sets up some sort of links or appends the source code directories to some path).

Comment: Thanks for coming back and reporting your findings. That's good karma!